# How to remove local build when executing Maven clean

Tags: maven

I'm using "clean -f pom.xml" (from intelliJ) to clean a Maven project. However, it doesn't remove the build located in the local m2 repo folder.

Is there a commandline statement option to remove the local build? (not the dependencies). Can it be set as default?

Comment: The `.m2/` directory contains your cache .. That will not be deleted every time... and why should it? Why using `mvn -f ... ` instead of `mvn clean` ...